# Karate Gatling report in pdf

Tags: karate

I want to share the performance test report generated by Karate to the stakeholders.

Can we generate the report in pdf format or do we have any other way to do so?

I checked at https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-gatling/ but couldn't find any option to do so?

Thanks in advance !!!

Abhi

Comment: as far as I know, no

Comment: @PeterThomas : If you don't know then nobody will know ;)

Comment: lol :) it may be possible to convert the gatling HTML into PDF by using chrome. see: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#chrome-java-api

Answer (score 0):

Karate gatling generates the report as Simulation.log file. This report further parse into .html format which is used for representation purposes. As such there is no direct way to do in the PDF format but you can write a simple java method to convert the .html file into .pdf format.
However, I would suggest to go ahead with .html format as it's serves the representation purpose.

Keep a note that there are still some limitations like with AWS pipeline, `aws` code build doesn't support the `gatling` karate report file in the pipeline.`

```
HtmlLoadOptions htmloptions = new HtmlLoadOptions();        
Document doc = new Document("Sample.html", htmloptions); 
doc.save("HTMLtoPDF.pdf");`
```

Thanks